# HP Access Switch 1920-48G POE switch

Tags: switch, layer1, fiber, hp, transceiver

I would like to know whether we can use an HP 1920-48G POE access switch with an HP 5406zl as Core switch. The access switch will be connected through 1 Gbps SFP to the core switch.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can. You just need to make sure that you are using compatible SFPs and the correct fiber for the SFP type.

Comment: Thank you very much. Can the 48th port can be configured as trunk or uplink port and connected to core switch using fiber

Comment: Any interface can be configured as a trunk interface. If the 48th port is SFP compatible, then you can use it as your trunk uplink.